# self hosting google's jsapi

Tags: jsapi

Is it legal to download the jsapi and self host it in my server instead of requesting it directly from the google's infrastructure?

I know that this is not recommended but is it legal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would take away all advantages of linking to Google's version on the CDN.

IANAL, it may not be legal, but it may be punishable by other future maintainers who wonder why you made that choice - just leave it on Google.

Answer (score 13):

Just for future reference of others that may find this page.

Google explicitly says that you can not download and self-host the loader, it is a violation of their ToS.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/faq.html#offline

Comment: That doesn't make it illegal.

Comment: I'd recommend not providing legal advice on a forum like this. The lines are gray here. https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/07/court-violating-terms-service-not-crime-bypassing and although you may be right, it's up for individuals to research whether it is illegal in their jurisdiction. Additionally, my post was simply to attempt to answer the spirit of the inquiry. The question was whether it was okay to self-host, and there's not much point to self-host if it goes against the ToS. Perhaps the user meant to say "Am I allowed to..." but if they need to know whether it is legal, get a lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that this is not recommended but is it legal?

Contact an attorney.